# Can God speak to non-prophets?

Tags: nevua-prophecy

Can God speak to non prophets, or do they simply become prophets the moment that God speaks to them?

Or to put it less philosophically. Can I as regular Joe ever hear the voice of God? Could God have a special message for non prophet Joe? Or does God's message to me make me a retroactive prophet?

Comment: Can I suggest an edit to "Does G-d" rather than "Can G-d"? If He can create a universe out of nothing, that particular task doesn't sound like much of a challenge, assuming He wants to tackle it...

Comment: It's not really a question about God's ability, but rather our classification. Christians say God can do what he wants, so God can become a human man and die. Judaism I think would say sure, God "could" do that, but that doesn't mean theologically we would consider it

Comment: Based on simyou's answer there are two approaches - prophets de-facto - people that G-d in fact addressed them personally, and prophets de-jure - those who *our Sages* count them as such.

Comment: @JoshK See my comment - whom do we call prophets - those who G-d speaks to or those who we want to call so.

Comment: He can do anything He wants to. He spoke in the form of a bat kol to plenty of non-prophets in the Talmud and probably afterwards, maybe even now.

Answer (score 2):

Usually we say that someone is a prophet as soon as God has spoken to them.
I understand your question to be if there are cases of God speaking to people who we know have not done any preparation and who have not learned to achieve a state which is conducive to prophecy.

Looking back to the earlier stories in Bereishis we find this a few times. God speaks to [Cain](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.4.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he), [Avimelech](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.20.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he), and [Laban](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.31.24?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he), none of whom are prophets.
Later we find God 'extending' from the prophecy of Moshe to the [seventy elders](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.11.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), who apparently were not worthy of prophecy on their own.

Comment: Also, king [Shaul](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%90_%D7%99/%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91) (שמואל א פרק י  פסוק יא). That actually became a phrase in Hebrew

Comment: So who/what defines a prophet?